# Voltage Standing Wave Ratio Derivation

Tags: waveform, microwave

[image: original]

[image: amplitude]

I don't understand how amplitude of incident and reflected voltage of wave equation comes out with 
\$e^{j2\beta z}\$ next to reflection coefficient. What is the meaning of it? Why is it part of the amplitude? How can I derive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transmission line introduces two primary factors that account for the application specific behavior of the transmission line: attenuation and phase delay. These factors dominate what differentiate a transmission line from normal lumped circuit analysis. While they are typically present in a lumped circuit, their effect is so minimal that it can be ignored. However, once the interconnections become longer than approximately 1/10 wavelength, the transmission line effects will become measurable and therefore should be factored into the analysis.

The attenuation constant and phase constant of a transmission line are expressed as α and β respectively. Both of these constants are frequency dependent. Combined, they form the complex propagation constant γ given as γ=α+jβ. Both attenuation and phase delay increase as the length of the transmission line increases. Skipping the lengthy proof, we can say that this effect is expressed as the complex term e<sup>γl</sup> where l is the length of the line. Given the voltage or current of the signal generator, it is now possible to predict the amplitude and phase of the voltage and current at any length l of a transmission line terminated in its characteristic impedance Z<sub>O</sub> or more generally, the amplitude and phase of the voltage and current of the incident (generator inducted) wave.

When a transmission line is not terminated in its characteristic impedance, a reflection of part or all of the incident energy occurs. The characteristics of the reflection include an amplitude and phase component. This complex term is given as Γ.

The reflected energy must also travel along the length of the line back toward the generator. As a result, the reflected wave once again encounters the e<sup>γl</sup> effect of the complex propagation constant but traveling in the reverse direction. But recall that what caused the reflection may also have introduced some attenuation (the returned energy compared to the incident energy) and phase change. The combined effect is therefore Γe<sup>γl</sup>. But this expresses the combined effect at the junction of the transmission line and the terminating impedance. To allow this effect to be determined at any point z along the line, as measured from the terminating impedance, we must account for the effect of the complex propagation constant as the incident energy travels from point z toward the terminating impedance and again as the reflected energy returns to point z. Since actual distance traveled is 2z, we arrive at the formula Γe<sup>γ2z</sup> to express the magnitude of the reflected wave at point z. By convention, reflected current is expressed as a negative term to indicate its direction of travel.

Therefore to determine the voltage or current at any point z along the transmission line, one must simply add the incident and reflected terms at position z along the line to arrive at the desired result. This is also defined as the amplitude of the standing wave at position z. It is also possible then to calculate the impedance at point z since the relative or absolute amplitude and phase of the voltage and current are easily calculated.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough answer! Now I understand where 2Bz came from!

Answer (score 0):

If you divide through by \$e^{-jBz}\$ you get \$1 - e^{2jBz}\$. That's point one.

Point two is Eulers equation where \$e^{j π} = -1\$. Also remember, in the second equation we are talking about \$|V_o|\$ i.e. magnitude.

Comment: If you divide by e^-jBz, what about V (z) on the left? Wouldn't the equation be V (z)e^jBz = V0[1+ㅏe^2jBz ]? How can I obtain magnitude from this equation? If i were to ignore the phase angle, wouldn't it be just |V (z)| = |V0||1+|ㅏ||? Why does e^2jBz still remain on the right side to effect the magnitude?

Comment: @Sysnaptic given euler's equation and magnitude I think the restoring e^-jBz can be equated to -1. Of course I could be wrong - the points I made are what immediately struck me on comparing A and B equations.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a standing /wave/, the amplitude varies with position. If it had the same amplitude everywhere, it would not be a /wave/. The wave happens because you drive the system with a sinusoid. The wave /stands/ because the incident and reflected waves are "traveling" in opposite directions.

Comment: For standing wave using cosine and sine, I get how the trig identity result in [2Vsin(Bz)]cos (wt) where amplitude , V, is doubled depending on position of z. Thus its amplitude is simply [2Vsin (Bz)] ignoring the phase part, cos (wt). But with exponent form, I can't seem to wrap my head around the derivation of amplitude resulting in incident amplitude + reflected amplitude times e^j2Bz.